# cURL of a Siteminder form returns an intermediate form

Tags: html, web-services, curl, siteminder

We are trying to automate the collection of XML data using cURL. The XML data is behind a Siteminder authenticator. This cURL statement is used to login to it:
`curl -s -k -L --ntlm -c cookies.txt -F "userid=username" -F "password=password" "https://example.com/data/xml"`

This example.com redirects to an internal siteminder form. After posting the credentials there is a slight issue.

The issue is that the cURL returns an intermediate HTML form which says, "This page is used to hold your data while you are being authorized for your request. You will be forwarded to continue the authorization process. If this does not happen automatically, please click the Continue button below." The form I will need to interact with is below, this is the intermediate form:

```
<FORM NAME="AUTOSUBMIT" 
    METHOD="POST" 
    ENCTYPE="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" 
    ACTION="https://example.com/siteminderagent/forms/IntranetRetry.fcc?SMQUERYDATA=-SM-...">
    <INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="SMPostPreserve" VALUE="...">
    <INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" VALUE="Continue">
</FORM>
```

Of course the autosubmit doesn't work as cURL just gets the HTML code of this intermediate page.
My question is, how do I get past this using cURL?

EDIT: The original form is:

```
<form method="post" id="login4m" name="login4m">
    <input type="text" value="User ID" name="USER" id="userid">
    <input type="password" value="" name="PASSWORD" id="password">
    <input type=hidden name=target value="HTTPS://example.com/data/xml">
    <input type=hidden name=smquerydata value="...">
    <input type=hidden name=smauthreason value="0">
    <input type=hidden name=smagentname value="archapps-agent">
    <input type=hidden name=postpreservationdata value="">
    <input type="text" value="Password" name="DUMMY" id="fakeput">
    <a href="#" id="loginbtn">Log In<span/></a>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The form tag details reveal that this is a "normal" form and not a multipart one, which means you should use curl's [-d option](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-d) and *not* -F

Also, you must submit the 'hidden' fields as well.

Comment: So the form I posted is actually the intermediate form that is returned after I curl the original one. I added the original one in the question.

Also, I used ... to represent an existing value, it's just that it was around 100 characters of what appears to be gibberish but really isn't.

Comment: it is still -d you need, and you need to post every single input field that has a name

Comment: Ok, but still after that it is the intermediate page HTML that is being returned. This HTML contains some text saying "Please wait while your credentials are being validated", and a form. How do I get past this form to the actual XML data?

Comment: Maybe it uses a redirect? Maybe javascript? Using cookies perhaps? The POST is probably just one step along a multi-step path...

Comment: Mhm, yeah I'm slowly tracing a fiddler stack for this process. Probably going to end up using python's urllib... Thanks for your help!